# Dropdownlist does not trigger the SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist (dr1) that is supposed to trigger the update of dr2 without affecting dr3. The problem is that dr1 triggers the update, but does not go into dr1_SelectedIndexChanged. I know that because the label does not change and that the pause does not happen

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="5">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <span style="color: Red">Updating.....</span>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dr1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dr1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dr2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dr1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dr3" runat="server" />
</form>
```

and my codebehind:

```
void Page_Load()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                java.Text = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\" type=\"text/javascript\">var sess = \"" + Session["username"] + "\";var user = \"" + Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "\";</script>";
                dr1.Items.Clear();
                dr2.Items.Clear();
                dr3.Items.Clear();
                dr1.Items.Add("");
                dr1.Items.Add("A");
                dr1.Items.Add("B");
                dr1.Items.Add("C");
                dr1.Items.Add("D");
                dr3.Items.Add("");
                dr3.Items.Add("Allo");
                dr3.Items.Add("Bonjour");
                dr3.Items.Add("Ola");
            }
        }

        protected void dr1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            dr2.Items.Clear();
            dr2.Items.Add("");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                dr2.Items.Add(dr1.SelectedValue + i);
        }
```

I hope that someone can help me

Thank you

Comment: Please get rid of the Sleep(5000);  That should never be put into production code. You're deliberately slowing it down, not a good idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It finally worked. After stripping the code and re-adding everything bit by bit, it worked.

I also deleted the dll and rebuilt it. That seems to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifythis line
 `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dr1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />`

And remove the `EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping everything in an updatepanel, and setting the Updatepanel's `UpdateMode="Always"`